# DHCP not affected or updated by link change

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, dhclient

My expectations are that when I swap the network cable `dhclient` will do a dance to either confirm the lease it has or discover a new address if the existing lease is not valid.

However, When I swap the cable I don't see any activity from `dhclient` at all.
On 16.04 (server), I don't see any log or (where I can inspect) any DHCP protocol traffic.

**Q. Is this expected behaviour?**

It seems optimistic to me. On my laptop running another OS I can happily swap cables as frequently as the DHCP negotiation permits, and always end up with a valid IP configuration.

**Q. Is there some other extra configuration that will link `ifup`/`ifdown` to `dhclient` to make it more proactive?**

Comment: By the way.... I'm not looking for CLI actions to fix the situation in an ad-hoc fashion.  I need a permanent solution so we can send devices out, to work on arbitrary networks, and need the locally configured VPN to come back up.

Comment: I never had this problem, when I change of network I get a new confiuration from DHCP. Check the **Network Paramter** configuration  and ensure that auto configuration is enable (Parameter --> Network --> Wired --> IPv4 --> Auto (DHCP)).

Comment: Sure thing.... `cat /etc/network/interfaces | grep enp3s0`   shows
`auto enp3s0`   and 
`iface enp3s0 inet dhcp`

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is the server installation.

Comment: Try to specify : `iface <interface> inet dhcp` in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @Eraseth can you see the previous comments?

Comment: Indeed. Sorry.  I tried with my Unbuntu server and that perfecty worked.